# Ring Oscillator

Tags: vhdl

I'm having some trouble implementing a ring oscillator. I don't care about it working on an FPGA. I only want to simulate using Xilinx ISE. Is the code below acceptable? I also addded the test bench. Thanks!

**Code**

---

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

-- 5 Ring Oscillator

entity ring_osc is
    port (ro_en : in std_logic;
            delay : in time;
            ro_out : out std_logic);
end ring_osc;

architecture behavioral of ring_osc is
    signal gate_out : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin
    process
    begin
        gate_out(0) <= ro_en and gate_out(5);
        wait for delay;
        gate_out(1) <= not(gate_out(0));
        wait for delay;
        gate_out(2) <= not(gate_out(1));
        wait for delay;
        gate_out(3) <= not(gate_out(2));
        wait for delay;
        gate_out(4) <= not(gate_out(3));
        wait for delay;
        gate_out(5) <= not(gate_out(4));
        wait for delay;
        ro_out <= gate_out(5);
    end process;

end behavioral;
```

**Test Bench**

---

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ring_osc_tb is
end ring_osc_tb;

architecture behavior of ring_osc_tb is 

    -- component declaration for the unit under test (uut)

    component ring_osc
        port (ro_en : in  std_logic;
              delay : in time;
              ro_out : out  std_logic);
    end component;


    -- Inputs
    signal ro_en : std_logic := '0';
    signal delay : time := 0.5 ns;

    -- Outputs
    signal ro_out : std_logic;

    signal clk : std_logic := '0';
    constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

begin

    -- instantiate the unit under test (uut)
    uut: ring_osc port map (
        ro_en => ro_en,
        delay => delay,
        ro_out => ro_out
    );

    -- clock process definitions
    clk_process :process
    begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
    end process;

    -- stimulus process
    stim_proc: process
    begin
        ro_en <= '1';
        delay <= 0.5 ns;
        wait for 10*clk_period;

        delay <= 1 ns;
        wait for 5*clk_period;

        assert false report "End of Simulation" severity failure;
    end process;

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process with sequential `wait` does not describe the concurrent nature of the gates in the [Ring oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_oscillator), since execution is suspended for `delay` time at each `wait`, which is not the way a real word design operates.

A description with concurrent evaluation of all the gates can be:

```
gate_out(0) <= ro_en and gate_out(5) after delay;

inv_g : for i in 1 to gate_out'high generate
  gate_out(i) <= not gate_out(i - 1) after delay;
end generate;

ro_out <= gate_out(5);
```

This is for simulation only, as also noted in the question, due to the inherent loop nature of a ring oscillator.

Using test bench, with added disable at start:

```
-- Disable at start
ro_en <= '0';
delay <= 0.5 ns;
wait for 10 * 0.5 ns;
```

Then the resulting waveform is:

[image]

Comment: The waveform seems incorrect:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gc1bd92bn6y1c0z/Capture.jpg.  
  
How about this:  
gate_out(0) <= ro_en and gate_out(5) after delay;  
gate_out(1) <= not(gate_out(0)) after 2*delay;  
gate_out(2) <= not(gate_out(1)) after 3*delay;  
gate_out(3) <= not(gate_out(2)) after 4*delay;  
gate_out(4) <= not(gate_out(3)) after 5*delay;  
gate_out(5) <= not(gate_out(4)) after 6*delay;  
ro_out <= gate_out(5);

Comment: Reason for the waveform in comment above, is that a disable with `ro_en = '0'` is not given time enough to ripple through the inverter chain at start, so the all 0's result in a 01010 after a delay, which is then repeated afterwards when enabled with `ro_en = '1'` right at start.  Try to update the test bench with disable `ro_en = '0'` and enough time to ripple through given the delay.